# How do I show the differentiation under integral sign when Leibnitz rule does not work?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In proving Taylor's theorem with remainder (in Tu's Manifold version)
I'm stuck at showing that $\int^1_0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} (p+t(x-p))dt$ is smooth. Here $f$ is smooth and it is defined on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Now the naive approach is to use Feynmann integration rule (or Leibnitz rule) but here we do not know if the derivative of integrand is bounded in $x$ for every $t\in[0,1]$, so we cannot bound the derivative with a nice integrable $g(t)$.

In the proof of Leibnitz rule, I don't know how to modify dominated convergence theorem. This should be an obvious question but I'm not sure how to show it. Thank you.

Comment: $f$ is assumed smooth right? Then you have more than enough to apply Leibniz's rule (keep in mind smoothness is a local property). For each point $p$ fix a closed ball around it. Then you even use a constant upper bound (extreme-value theorem). In fact, using uniform continuity one can give a very 'elementary' proof of Leibniz's rule which doesn't appeal to Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: that totally makes sense.. Derivative is indeed a local property. Thanks so much!